# PHP warning and PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, http-status-code-500

I am getting this message 100 times in my error log and my site is down right now  with the message"website is currently unable to handle this request.

`HTTP ERROR 500`

> "PHP Warning: 
>   require(/home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/post.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-settings.php on line 142 PHP
>   Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/post.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-settings.php on line 142

Comment: If this file is not required in the current execution then you can change require to include.

Answer (score 0):

the error message is clear enough. WordPress looks for the `/home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/post.php` file which is missing. The 500 error code indicates that there was a server error. Make sure that the file is available where WordPress it expects to be.